# mongoose error Cast to ObjectId failed for value xxx with postman

Tags: mongoose

When following a mongoose tutorial, a schema field named `followers` has the type as an array of `ObjectId` : 
`followers:[Schema.Types.ObjectId]`

i used postman to submit a new document and the POST data has the JSON format:

```
{
"title":"test title999",
"text":"test text999b",
"meta":[1, [], 'three', { four: 5 }],
"followers":["582ff61afe100611809e7fa5"]
}
```

The application's express POST route has a validate method and i didn't have any problem with all fields except with the metionned one above as i got this error:

```
{
     "message": "Post validation failed",
     "name": "ValidationError",
     "errors ":{
       "followers ":
         {"message ":"Cast to ObjectID failed for value\ "[ '\"577f9cecd71d71fa1fb6f43a\ "' ]\" at path \"followers\"",
          "name": "CastError",
          "kind": "ObjectID ",
          "value ":["\"577f9cecd71d71fa1fb6f43a\""],
          "path": "followers",
          "reason": {
              "message ":"Cast to ObjectId failed for value\ "[ '\"577f9cecd71d71fa1fb6f43a\"' ]\" at path\ "followers\"",
              "name": "CastError",
              "kind": "ObjectId",
              "value": ["\"577f9cecd71d71fa1fb6f43a\ ""],
              "path": "followers"
          }
      }
   }
 }
```

**---- EDIT -----**

The validate method in the POST route :

```
app.post('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
    var post = new Post(req.body);
    post.validate(function(error){
        console.log("\n\n validate error : " + JSON.stringify(error) + "\n\n");
        if(error) return next(error);
        post.save(function(error, result){
            console.log("\n\n save error : " + JSON.stringify(error) + "\n\n");
        if(error) return next(error);
        res.send(result); 
    });
    });

});
```

and the model :

```
var postSchema = new Schema({
    title:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        trim:true,
        match:/^([\w ,.!?]{1,100})$/
    }, 
    text:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        max:2000
    },
    followers:[Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    meta:Schema.Types.Mixed,
    viewCounter:Number,
    published:Boolean,
    createdAt:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now,
        required:true
    },
    updatedAt:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now,
        required:true
    }

});
```

Comment: Would you provide more details about your validation method? your model?

Comment: done, it's updated

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach a reference to `followers` attribute in `post` model, assuming the other model is called `user` so it would be as follow:

```
followers: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
```

Read more about referencing in mongoose from [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

Answer (score 0):

After reading some more examples for using embedded documents in mongoose(as [this one](http://code.runnable.com/VS6ChjG7W1pSzbY9/inserting-data-with-reference-foreign-key-from-express-using-mongoose-and-mongodb-for-node-js)) Voila the solution i found :
The `followers` field value comes as a `String` in the `body.req` object and cannot be automatically converted to an `ObjectId`. By parsing it :

```
req.body.followers = JSON.parse(followers);
```

it was possible to save it among other fields. The POST route became like this:

```
app.post('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
    req.body.followers = JSON.parse(req.body.followers);
    var post = new Post(req.body);
    post.validate(function(error){
        console.log("\n\n validate error : " + JSON.stringify(error) + "\n\n");
        if(error) return next(error);
        post.save(function(error, result){
            console.log("\n\n save error : " + JSON.stringify(error) + "\n\n");
        if(error) return next(error);
        res.send(result); 
    });
    });

});
```

Hence, the POST request cannot be 100% dynamic and some specific convertions must be done before the save process. As for Basim Hennawi answer no need for the ref field to be added to the schema's field.